# SSL operation failed with code 1: dh key too small

Tags: php, codeigniter, ssl, mysqli, openssl

I am connecting to my database Google Cloud SQL via SSL. I use codeigniter 3.0 to do so, although the mysqli driver is a bit modified to allow this functionality.

It's been working well for months. However it *just* started to return this warning:

```
Message: mysqli::real_connect(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:14082174:SSL routines:SSL3_CHECK_CERT_AND_ALGORITHM:dh key too small
```

I'm assuming `DH Key is too small` is the main problem, but I have no idea what that means. I've googled Diffie–Hellman key exchange, along with the message "key too small" but I haven't had much luck.

Is this a sign that the keys on the server have been tampered with? I've checked the last-modified dates on them -- no abnormal recent access.

It could be that my server did some upgrading to PHP or their server configuration, which may result in this breaking, but I wanted to check and make sure that it wasn't something else.

Thanks for any insight / readable material on the subject.

Comment: Try to change SSLCipherSuite in httpd.conf file

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> ```
> ... error:14082174:SSL routines:SSL3_CHECK_CERT_AND_ALGORITHM:dh key too small
> ```

The error number you are interested in is the OpenSSL error 0x14082174.

The `SSL3_CHECK_CERT_AND_ALGORITHM` is usually seen when enabling export grade ciphers. It may be showing up again in non-export grade negotiations due to Logjam (see below).

---

> I'm assuming DH Key is too small is the main problem, but I have no idea what that means. I've googled Diffie–Hellman key exchange, along with the message "key too small" but I haven't had much luck.

That's due to the recent [Logjam attack](https://weakdh.org/) from the paper [Imperfect Forward Secrecy: How Diffie-Hellman Fails in Practice](https://weakdh.org/imperfect-forward-secrecy.pdf).

You should use 2048-bit Diffie-Hellman groups or larger. You should ***not*** be using 512-bit or 1024-bit Diffie-Hellman groups.

The first thing to check for is your cipher list string. It should be similar to:

```
"HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5:!RC4"
```

It will avoid the export grade ciphers, and use modern ciphers. But you will also need to ensure your DH callback is not using a weak/small field size. For that, you need to check the server configuration.

---

Some folks are "solving" the issue with `kRSA`. `kRSA` is a key ***transport*** scheme, not a key ***agreement*** scheme. The RSA key transport scheme does not provide forward secrecy, and its use is usually discouraged. In fact, its going to be removed from TLS 1.3.

I can only say *"usually discouraged"* because it depends on the data being protected. If you have SSL/TLS to guard downloads of a publicly available file, then its probably OK to use. If your website has a login, then its probably a little risky to use it because the password is secret data (unlike the publicly downloadable file).

To avoid key transport and pass those [Qualsys SSL Labs](https://www.ssllabs.com/) tests for web server configurations and forward secrecy, use:

```
"HIGH:!aNULL:!kRSA:!MD5:!RC4"
```

In your Apache configuration file, it would look like so:

```
# cat /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf | grep SSLCipherSuite
# SSLCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM:!aNULL:!MD5
SSLCipherSuite HIGH:!aNULL:!kRSA:!MD5:!RC4
```

---

I seem to recall `wget` rejected small groups quite some time before the paper was released. It might make a good test case for your site.

There's also an improved [sslscan](https://github.com/rbsec/sslscan), which tests for lots of things. That might make a good QA tool, too.