# MySQL error when using remote connections with SSL

Tags: php, mysql, ssl, encryption

I installed a mysql server on a host and I would like to connect from another host to the mysql server with encrypted connections (both run Ubuntu 12.04). I already created and transmitted the certificates and tested the setup manually. I can connect to the remote mysql server using the key and certificate from the Linux command line, so the server configuration seems to be correct:

```
$ mysql -h x.x.x.x -u user01 -p --ssl-ca=ca.pem --ssl-cert=cert.pem --ssl-key=key.pem
```

The established connection (after entering the password) is encrypted and everything seems fine:

```
 mysql> show status like 'Ssl_cipher';
 +---------------+--------------------+
 | Variable_name | Value              |
 +---------------+--------------------+
 | Ssl_cipher    | DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA |
 +---------------+--------------------+
 1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

However, if I try to connect to the mysql server in PHP it's not working:

```
$obj = mysqli_init();
mysqli_options($obj, MYSQLI_OPT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT, 5);
mysqli_ssl_set($obj, "/etc/mysql/key.pem", "/etc/mysql/cert.pem", "/etc/mysql/ca.pem", null, null);
mysqli_real_connect($obj, NODE_IP, NODE_USER, NODE_PASSWORD, NODE_DATABASE);
```

I get the following error:

```
PHP Warning:  mysqli_real_connect(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:14082174:SSL routines:SSL3_CHECK_CERT_AND_ALGORITHM:dh key too small in /var/www/internal/test.php on line 11
```

When I define a cipher, e.g. ""DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA" in the mysqli_ssl_set function (last argument), I get the same error,
even the same cipher was used in the manual connection from the command line that acutally worked (see above). When I define a stronger cipher, like "ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384", I get a new error message:

```
PHP Warning:  mysqli_real_connect(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:140830B5:SSL routines:SSL3_CLIENT_HELLO:no ciphers available in /var/www/internal/test.php on line 11
```

I have no idea whats wrong, any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: What are your MySQL and OpenSSL versions? This might be related: http://serverfault.com/questions/700747/how-to-fix-logjam-vulnerability-with-mysql

Comment: I haven't got problems with PDO, so, it must be MySQLi.

Comment: Also see [SSL operation failed with code 1: DH key too small](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30701397).

Answer (score 1):

I could solve this Diffie-Hellman key-length issue just by using "AES256-SHA" in the cipher specifications of mysqli_ssl_set().

Thanks!

Comment: You save me! Mark your answer as correct. Many thanks. How did you get that string?