# How to get the error string in openssl?

Tags: ssl, openssl, tls1.2

I am using openssl to establish the TLS connection with the remote server.

Here are the code snippets:

```c
if ((ret = SSL_connect(c->ssl)) <= 0) {
    ret = SSL_get_error(c->ssl, ret);
    if((err = ERR_get_error())) {
        SSL_load_error_strings();
        ERR_load_crypto_strings();
        CRERROR(LOGSSLUTILS, "SSL connect err code:[%lu](%s)\n", err, ERR_error_string(err, NULL));
        CRERROR(LOGSSLUTILS, "Error is %s \n",ERR_reason_error_string(err));
    }
}
```

for some unknown reason, the ssl_connect failed and I just want to identify the reason by using the ERR_error_string, the outputs are:

```
SSL connect err code:[336077172] (error:14082174:lib(20):func(130):reason(372))

Error: cmrSSLlInit:174 Error is (null)
```

As you can see, I can only get the error code but cannot get the readable error string.

How how can I get the readable error string ?

Answer (score 10):

> for some unknown reason, the ssl_connect failed and I just want to
> identify the reason by using the ERR_error_string, the outputs are:
>
> ```
> SSL connect err code:[336077172] (error:14082174:lib(20):func(130):reason(372))
> ```

```
$ openssl errstr 0x14082174
error:14082174:SSL routines:ssl3_check_cert_and_algorithm:dh key too small
```

For *`DH key too small`*, checkout [SSL operation failed with code 1: dh key too small](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30701397/608639) on Stack Overflow. The short of it is, earlier versions of OpenSSL used a 512-bit DH group. Its too small, and you need to use a 2048-bit group.

---

> How how can I get the readable error string ?

To log a string like *`error:14082174:SSL routines:ssl3_check_cert_and_algorithm:dh key too small`*, I believe you can call `err_print_errors` and `ERR_print_errors_fp`. The functions print the entire error stack. Also see the [`ERR_print_errors` man pages](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/man3/ERR_print_errors_fp.html).

Answer (score 8):

One way to get all queued thread local errors is with the snippet below as suggested [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSSL/Error_handling):

```
string getOpenSSLError()
{
    BIO *bio = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());
    ERR_print_errors(bio);
    char *buf;
    size_t len = BIO_get_mem_data(bio, &buf);
    string ret(buf, len);
    BIO_free(bio);
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 5):

i use this to print the latest error

```
ctx = SSL_CTX_new(method);
if(ctx == NULL)
{
    printf("%s", ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), NULL));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are calling `SSL_load_error_strings()` and `ERR_load_crypto_strings()` too late in your sample code. They should be called right up front at the start of your program - you should then get readable error strings out of OpenSSL. @jww has it right about the DH group being too small. Ideally the server needs to be reconfigured with a larger group. If that is not possible then try connecting with a non-DHE ciphersuite (i.e. use an ECDHE based one instead)

Answer (score 2):

This is because I include the option "no-err" when compile openssl.　so the Err_error_string return NULL