# BIO_read with blocking socket returns SSL_ERROR_NONE. What caused this?

Tags: c++, ssl, openssl, network-programming, tls1.2

I'm using OpenSSL Bio interface with a blocking socket to create a TCP SSL connection.

After many successful send/reads...

`BIO_write()` succeeds. Immediately I progress to wait for the response but `BIO_read()` fails. I process the return value using OpenSSL enums but it maps to `SSL_ERROR_NONE`?

Given it's a blocking socket, is the only explanation the client MUST have closed the connection? It doesn't make much sense for the client to close the connection in this case. Are there any other possibilities, or ways to determine the exact reason?

This is how the code looks:

```
std::optional<Response> sendThenRecv()
{
    // .....

    if(BIO_write(bio_, write_buf, strlen(write_buf)) <= 0)
    {
        return std::nullopt;
    }

    const int res = BIO_read(bio_, read_buf, read_size);

    if(res <= 0)
    {
        LOG("BIO_read() failed. errno details: " << GetSSLError(res));
        return std::nullopt;
    }

    //.....
}

static inline std::string GetSSLError(const int reason)
{
    switch(reason)
    {
        case 0:
            return "SSL_ERROR_NONE";

        case 1:
            return "SSL_ERROR_SSL";

        case 2:
            return "SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ";

        case 3:
            return "SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE";

        case 4:
            return "SSL_ERROR_WANT_X509_LOOKUP";

        case 5:
            return "SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL: " + std::string(strerror(errno));

        case 6:
            return "SSL_ERROR_ZERO_RETURN";

        case 7:
            return "SSL_ERROR_WANT_CONNECT";

        case 8:
            return "SSL_ERROR_WANT_ACCEPT";

        case 9:
            return "SSL_ERROR_WANT_ASYNC";

        case 10:
            return "SSL_ERROR_WANT_ASYNC_JOB";

        case 11:
            return "SSL_ERROR_WANT_CLIENT_HELLO_CB";

        case 12:
            return "SSL_ERROR_WANT_RETRY_VERIFY";
        default:
            MY_ASSERT(false);
    }

    return std::to_string(reason);
}
```

Comment: Off-topic: do not map errors by yourself. You can fetch user friendly error discretion from  OpenSSL library: https://stackoverflow.com/q/42106339/1387438

Comment: `BIO_read()` returning zero is not necessarily an indication of an error. See the *man* page. It could mean that the peer has disconnected, for example, or that you provided a zero length parameter.

Comment: @user207421 I will add an assert on the zero length parameter. If we assume this was okay and  `SSL_ERROR_NONE` is correct, is client disconnection the only possible reason?

Comment: You should treat return values of 0 and -1 separately. As with `read()`, I would treat 0 as a disconnect and -1 as an error, but the *man* page is deplorably vague on the topic.

Comment: [`BIO_read`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/BIO_read.html) doesn't return the error codes in `GetSSLError`

Comment: @AlanBirtles Should I still use the link from the first comment?

Comment: I doubt it because you aren't getting an error, just no data

Comment: @AlanBirtles This is a blocking socket, why would it return if there was no data? Surely it would just block?

Comment: There's an overhead to ssl, the socket may well have returned some data but there was no actual application payload