# Ignore Weak SSL Algorithm in PHP streamcontext/curl/soap

Tags: php, ssl, soap, diffie-hellman

**Statement**: At the beginning I would like to state, that I'm well aware (and want to inform others) that this is not the proper way of doing things. If soultion is found, use it as last resort.

**My problem** is Weak Algorithm. And can't find a way to skip checks.
Company which exposes me endpoint states it is secure and they're not going to upgrade SSL Certificate. I know it's insecure, but can't do anything and must *obey* their decision.

Error i get *file_get_contents(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:14082174:SSL routines:ssl3_check_cert_and_algorithm:dh key too small*
and *file_get_contents(): Failed to enable crypto in...*

My code is:

```
$context = stream_context_create([
    'http' => [
        'timeout' => 5,
    ],
    'ssl' => [
        // set some SSL/TLS specific options
        'verify_peer' => false,
        'verify_peer_name' => false,
        'allow_self_signed' => true
    ]
]);
var_dump(file_get_contents($wsdl, false, $context));
```

In browser i ge `SSL_ERROR_WEAK_SERVER_EPHEMERAL_DH_KEY` and information about weak `Diffie Hellman` key.

I'm looking for a way to disable this check.

Most preferably via streamContext which I can use in `SoapClient`

Comment: instead of `file_get_contents` use curl(), it has a flag for ignoring ssl issues

Comment: Dunno but check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30701397/ssl-operation-failed-with-code-1-dh-key-too-small

Comment: @rtfm first curl does not work with `soapClient` as far as I'm aware. Can't do. Secondly, curl allows to ignore peer and server checks, but not weak algorithm checks

Comment: I think the flags that curl offers are just the same verify_peer flags being used here. I believe the issue here is that your system is newer than theirs, and is refusing to use what it now knows to be an insecure technique. To get around it, you'd probably need to downgrade your openssl library to an outdated version.

Comment: @AbraCadaver Seen that post. From it I know i have to disable algorithm checks. But couldn't find how

Comment: @AlexHowansky I was afraid of it...

Comment: Note -- I do **not** suggest actually downgrading. I hope you can use this position as a bargaining chip to indicate to your supervisor that it's unreasonable for you to work with this client. "But boss, in order to hit their API, we'd need to intentionally cripple the security on our own system..." :)

Comment: If something is this out of date with its encryption algos, chances are it's also available under http?

Comment: @apokryfos Ha ha ha sad but true.

Comment: It's Intranet system with 1 exposed port. Currently writing email explaining that mozilla and other standard-creating companies removed this algorithm from support. And that it is not much more secure than plain http (Hey boss, let's disable SSL, it only wastes resoruces in state it is in now... hope that will)
Main problem is, it is other company serving them SASS service written in .net or something and using SOAP instead of REST/json... I'm so mad tbh...

Comment: It's worth pointing out that this message has nothing at all to do with the SSL certificate. It is about the ephemeral DH key that the server has offered to use. I don't know PHP but a solution might be to use only pure RSA ciphersuites, assuming the client offers one.

Comment: I realized it yesterday when they did not change certificate, but rather than that (i think) updated SSL/TLS libraries.

Answer (score 1):

You need disable Diffie Hellman validation:

```php
$context = stream_context_create(array(
    'ssl' => array(
        'ciphers' => 'DEFAULT:!DH',
...
```

If need disable the validation of the certificate you need:

```php
$context = stream_context_create(array(
    'ssl' => array(
        'ciphers'           => 'DEFAULT:!DH',
        'verify_peer'       => false,
        'verify_peer_name'  => false,
        'allow_self_signed' => true
    )
);
```